# Change Firebase Auth `FB` and `G+` providers to `Email & Password` login

Tags: ios, facebook, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, ionic3

I have an `Ionic 3` app and uses `cordova-ios": "4.5.5"`. That means I need to use Xcode old build system to build the app with Xcode 12+. It is working fine and no issues.

But my problem here is G+ and FB logins are not working with the above build system. I use G+: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/google-plus/

And FB: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/facebook/

But both are not working and the above FB plugin is deprecated and they tell to use a new one here: https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/issues/885

But I can't use that since it uses the new iOS build system. If I'll use the new build system with the Ionic 3 app then it'll give a lot of issues for all other plugins and so many issues. So I have decided to stay on the old build system. And disable the FB and G+ logins for the iOS platform.

`Note:` All are working perfectly fine on the Android platform.

So then I have a problem with existing `FB` And `G+` users.

So is there any way to change the Firebase Auth `FB` and `G+` providers to `Email & Password` login for the already existing users or any other alternative?

Any idea about how to use this method with my use case? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking#link-email-address-and-password-credentials-to-a-user-account

It says this

```
1. Sign in the user using any authentication provider or method.
2. Prompt the user for an email address and new password.
```

Since `FB` and `G+` are not working on the iOS platform on my build environment how can I achieve 1st step above?

I don't know how will this help the already existing users? i.e. due to not working `FB` and `G+`, I need to remove those logins. Existing users mean they have already logged in to the app using Social login. If I'll remove social logins then next time how they can log in if they'll Sign-out?

You know that mobile app users do not sign out regularly. But if they'll do that then?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can [link email+password credentials to the existing account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking#link-email-address-and-password-credentials-to-a-user-account).

After linking that, the user can log in with the new email+password credentials or with the original social provider. In either case they'll end up signed in to the same Firebase Authentication account.

Comment: I don't know how will this help the already existing users? i.e. due to not working `FB` and `G+`, I need to remove that login. Existing users mean they have already logged in to the app using Social login. If I'll remove social logins then next time how they can log in if they Sign out?